# Calculate and Display Disk Usage

Tags: coldfusion, charts, coldfusion-8

Using CF8, I want to produce a graph that displays the disk usage, in megabytes, per client.  The clients are the directories within D:\inetpub\sites.

I've looked through the docs and found examples only using DB queries.  I am using `<cfdirectory>` to get a list of directories.

```
<cfdirectory action="list" 
  directory="#expandPath("../../")#"
  name="webDirectories">

<cfquery name="getInfo" dbtype="query">
    select    sum(size) as total, name
    from    webDirectories
    group by name
</cfquery>




<h1>Web Server Disk Usage Analysis</h1>  
<!--- Bar graph, from Query of Queries ---> 
<cfchart format="flash"  
    xaxistitle="Client"  
    yaxistitle="Disk Usage">  

<cfchartseries type="bar"  
    query="getInfo"  
    itemcolumn="name"  
    valuecolumn="size"> 

  <cfoutput query="getInfo">
    <cfchartdata item="#name#" value=#Round(total/1000)*1000#>
  </cfoutput> 
</cfchartseries> 
</cfchart>
```

I would like to have the clients listed in the x-axis and usage on the y-axis.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your chart code is wrong. I changed it to this, and it worked for me:

```
<h1>Web Server Disk Usage Analysis</h1>  
<!--- Bar graph, from Query of Queries ---> 
<cfchart format="flash"  
    xaxistitle="Client"  
    yaxistitle="Disk Usage">  

    <cfchartseries type="bar"  
        query="getInfo"  
        itemcolumn="name"  
        valuecolumn="total" />

</cfchart>
```

If you want to do your `round(total/100)*1000`, you can just massage the query further before feeding it into the chart.